# firefox transitions breaking when parent overflow is changed

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions

i came across an issue today and it took me so long to debug, I couldn't find a solution anywhere online so I thought it would be useful to document

It seems that transitions do not work on Firefox if the parent's "overflow" property is changed together with the transition - ie:

```
.parent { overflow: hidden; }
.parent:hover { overflow: visible; }
.child { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s linear; }
.parent:hover .child { opacity: 0; }
```

The transitions will not work on the child. Remove the "overflow:visible" property from the hovered parent, and everything is ok. It seems that changing the overflow on the child itself does not cause any issues, which is weird.

Here's a js fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/qzMj9/13/

does anyone know why this happens? is it a ff bug or the correct functionality? it works on webkit!

Comment: Yick, just encountered this myself. So much time wasted. This bug is still present as of v25. Thanks for posting the issue! If anyone is triggering the overflow change via javascript you can hack around the issue with a setTimeout event with duration of 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289 to me: the parent is having its CSS boxes reconstructed, which loses the old computed style on the child, which means no transition start, since that's triggered by computed style changes.

Comment: They say it was fixed but in Version 33.0.2 on Mac, the above example does not work.

Comment: @Seka See the "Target Milestone" field in the bug report.  It's fixed in Firefox 34.  You can try that at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#beta

Comment: I confirm, it's fixed in FF34