# Transition on an element while body has an overflow:hidden in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

So, the title of this question might not be very clear, but have a look at this fiddle which illustrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcXmV/

When you run the script in a webkit browser, you'll see the .overlay div animating upwards. However, this is currently not working on Firefox. It does work in Firefox when I remove the `overflow:hidden` in the state-overlay class. This is necessary however for other reasons not shown in the example.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there's a way to work around this?

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626412/firefox-transitions-breaking-when-parent-overflow-is-changed

Comment: Do you need overflow:hidden?

Comment: 3rror404: It appears to be the same issue. Thanks.

etangins: Yes, I need it for other reasons not shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the body has overflow: hidden then maybe this helps you:

```
body { overflow:hidden; } 
body.state-overlay .overlay { 
  transform: none; 
}
```

I changed the

```
body.state-overlay { overflow: hidden; }
```

to:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

I tested it and it works fine, hope it helps you

Comment: In my case the body only needs to have an overflow:hidden when it has the state-overlay class. Thanks though :)

Comment: Ok I try to find another solution

Comment: It seems to be a browser bug, so I don't think there is a solution. I'll have to look for a workaround.

Comment: Try this: body>.state-overlay {overflow: hidden;} Also worked for me

Comment: The body has no overflow:hidden there. Thanks for the help but I'm pretty sure there isn't a solution, as it is a bug in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

i changed `body.state-overlay` to `body .state-overlay`

and now it working on chrome and firefox

## Demo

Comment: Eh, yes, but I want the body to have an overflow:hidden, which it doesn't have in your example :)

Comment: @Leon ok, i will check it again! if i find a way, i will share it ;)

Comment: @Leon now! body have an `overflow:hidden` , and it works fine ... http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/kcXmV/4/

Comment: Yes, but it only needs an overflow hidden when it has the state-overlay class :) Thanks for the help, but I'm pretty sure there is no solution as this is a browser bug.